# Method that verifies if a list contains a string from a different list

Tags: java

Is there a method that can validate that given two lists,

```
List<String> models;
List<String> titleOfVehicle;
```

that one of the `models` must be contained in each of the `titleOfVehicle`.

For example, given the following:

```
models = {Accord, Civic, Element}
titleOfVehicle1 = {2014 Honda Accord, 2011 Toyota Camry}
titleOfVehicle2 = {2013 Honda Accord, 2015 Honda Element, 2011 Honda Civic}
```

then when comparing `models` and `titleOfVehicle1` it will fail since `2011 Toyota Camry` does not contain one of the models provided. However, `titleOfVehicle2` will pass since it contains a model for each vehicle titles.

---

I already created an algorithm that does this, however, whenever I create an algorithm it seems like there is already a method that does it, so I am wondering if there is an already built method that does this?

Comment: There is no builtin method that will check *substrings* of another list.

Comment: If you're on Java 8 (Lambdas), you can probably do the check quite fluently in a one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in for this, but you can come up with a one-liner, following the Java 8 functional style:

```
titleOfVehicle.stream().allMatch(
    title -> models.stream().anyMatch(title::contains)
)
```

Comment: I am not under java 8 yet but after seeing this I will be soon lol. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Since **OP** isn't using Java 8 yet so I thought I will contribute the long winded way, which can get the job done as well.

**Code:**

```
private void doIt() {
    List<String> models = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Accord", "Civic", "Element"));
    List<String> titleOfVehicle1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("2014 Honda Accord", "2011 Toyota Camry"));
    List<String> titleOfVehicle2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("2013 Honda Accord", "2015 Honda Element", "2011 Honda Civic"));

    boolean hasAllModels = true;
    for (String model : models) {
        boolean foundModel = false;
        for (String title : titleOfVehicle2) {
            if (title.contains(model)) {
                foundModel = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!foundModel) {
            hasAllModels = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (hasAllModels) {
        System.out.print("Yay found one that matches it!.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("The list does not contain all of the models that you are looking for.");
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new test().doIt();
}
```

**Algorithm:**
The logic here is that I first loop through all of the models in `models` list. Then, for this instance, I go through the String in `titleOfVehicle2` - one by one using the `contains` String API to check whether the entire word e.g. `2014 Honda Accord` contains the word `Accord`.

If yes, then we know it has passes the first test, then this goes on until all of the `model` words are found.

Not an interesting solution but probably the `contains` API is the highlight here. You might want to check it out.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)